# Is there a way to check(or print) the scaled X_train at RandomizedSearchCV in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

I wonder if there is a way to check(or to print) the scaled(StandardScaler) X_train
after the RandomizedSearchCV or pipeline.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler    
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# get some data
iris = load_digits()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.3, random_state=777)

# specify parameters and distributions to sample from
param_dist = {
          'rbf_svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 
          'rbf_svm__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 
          'rbf_svm__kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
}

# create pipeline with a scaler 
steps01 = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('rbf_svm', SVC())]
pipeline01 = Pipeline(steps01)

# do search
search01 = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline01, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=50)
search01.fit(x_train, y_train)

print('best parameters with scaler  : ', search01.best_params_)
print('best score with scaler : ', search01.best_score_)
```

Comment: I even checked the storage in my MacBook. But I couldn't find it.

Comment: This - `search01.best_estimator_.named_steps['scaler'].transform(x_train)` - might be a way, i.e. accessing the `'scaler'` step of your fitted pipeline and then transforming your dataset

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment. ^____^ I'll try the way you taught me.